# Python Dictionaries, mathematically add a numeric value to existing key value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

How can I mathematically add a numeric value to existing key value in Python Dictionaries?
e.g

```
inventory = {'Motherboard' : 75, 'Amplifier IC' : 55}
```

so if I want to add 15 to existing `75` of `'Motherboard'`, how can I do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`+=` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) with `inventory['Motherboard']` as the target of the assignment:

```
>>> inventory = {'Motherboard' : 75, 'Amplifier IC' : 55}
>>> inventory['Motherboard'] += 15
>>> inventory
{'Motherboard': 90, 'Amplifier IC': 55}
```

Comment: I did a long stupid way, but thanks again!                                                     >>> inventory['Motherboard'] = inventory['Motherboard'] + 15